# Displaying CAD file in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cad

CAD file does not appear in ArcMap while in Autocad it is showing and working correctly.
Even the attribute table is empty.
What could be the reason?

Comment: They should appear. Try to import a CAD file (e.g. a DWG) via the catalog window, and then right click on it in the Table of Content and click "Zoom to Layer". If you have a project in ArcMap with some file already imported, the CAD file is probably not in visible because it's not overlapping onto the other layers.

Comment: Thanx , Yes it should appear but doesn't ............ any way Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that can get your job done is this : wBlock your drawing and use from ArcToolbox > Feature to Polygon to your block. This should insert your drawing with it's layers in attribute table.

Comment: Yup ............. I did and it works,